# how to add clickable element on react-js using array type of jsx.element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'd like to make my react-js element into a clickable component on an array-type component using `JSX.Element` but it seems wrong.

I've done on the first index on `id:1` the `href` tag but it's not opening external links.

here is my code:

```js
const Movies: React.FC = () => {  
  const getMovies = (): JSX.Element[] => {
    return [{
      desc: "A tale of some people watching over a large portion of space.",
      id: 1,
      icon: "fa-solid fa-galaxy",
      href: "www.wikipedia.com",
      image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596727147705-61a532a659bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bWFydmVsfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
      title: "Protectors of the Milky Way"
    }, {
      desc: "Some people leave their holes to disrupt some things.",
      id: 2,
      icon: "fa-solid fa-hat-wizard",
      image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535666669445-e8c15cd2e7d9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8bG9yZCUyMG9mJTIwdGhlJTIwcmluZ3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
      title: "Hole People"
    }, {
      desc: "A boy with a dent in his head tries to stop a bad guy. And by bad I mean bad at winning.",
      id: 3,
      icon: "fa-solid fa-broom-ball",
      image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632266484284-a11d9e3a460a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTZ8fGhhcnJ5JTIwcG90dGVyfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
      title: "Pot of Hair"
    }, {
      desc: "A long drawn out story of some people fighting over some space. Cuz there isn't enough of it.",
      id: 4,
      icon: "fa-solid fa-starship-freighter",
      image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533613220915-609f661a6fe1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3RhciUyMHdhcnN8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
      title: "Area Fights"
    }].map((movie: any) => {
      const styles: React.CSSProperties = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${movie.image})`  
      }
      
      const id: string = `movie-card-${movie.id}`;
      
      return (
        <div key={movie.id} id={id} className="movie-card">
          <div class="container" className="movie-card-background background-image" style={styles} /><a href="https://www.w3docs.com/"></a><span class="link"></span>
          <div className="movie-card-content">
            <div className="movie-card-info">
              <span className="movie-card-title">{movie.title}</span>
              <span className="movie-card-desc">{movie.desc}</span>
              <span classNAme="movie-card-href">{movie.href}</span>
            </div>
            <i className={movie.icon} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
```

As you see I'm copying this code for my webs and still learning about react-js.

Comment: From what I understand, you want to be able to click the link and have it open. Instead of using a ```<span/>``` for the ```movie.href```, use something like this: ```<a href={movie.href}>{movie.href}</a>```.

Comment: @EthanKrug putting the <a> tag like that will just add the text with a link and not the whole clickable from the image, hope u understand what im saying. but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the elements clickable in your React component, you can wrap the content inside an `<a>` tag and provide the href attribute with the desired URL. However, in your code, you are currently placing the `<a>` tag outside the wrapping `<div>` element, which will not make the entire card clickable.

To fix this, you should wrap the entire content inside the `<a>` tag and provide the href dynamically using the movie.href value. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
const Movies: React.FC = () => {
  const getMovies = (): JSX.Element[] => {
    return [
      {
        desc: "A tale of some people watching over a large portion of space.",
        id: 1,
        icon: "fa-solid fa-galaxy",
        href: "https://www.wikipedia.com",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596727147705-61a532a659bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bWFydmVsfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        title: "Protectors of the Milky Way",
      },
      // Rest of the movies...
    ].map((movie: any) => {
      const styles: React.CSSProperties = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${movie.image})`,
      };

      const id: string = `movie-card-${movie.id}`;

      return (
        <a key={movie.id} href={movie.href} className="movie-card">
          <div
            id={id}
            className="container movie-card-background background-image"
            style={styles}
          ></div>
          <span className="link"></span>
          <div className="movie-card-content">
            <div className="movie-card-info">
              <span className="movie-card-title">{movie.title}</span>
              <span className="movie-card-desc">{movie.desc}</span>
              <span className="movie-card-href">{movie.href}</span>
            </div>
            <i className={movie.icon} />
          </div>
        </a>
      );
    });
  };

  return <div>{getMovies()}</div>;
};

export default Movies;
```

In the updated code, I moved the `<a>` tag to wrap the entire card content and set the href attribute to movie.href. Now, clicking on the movie card will open the respective URL specified in the href property of each movie object.

Comment: This answers, as with all 6 answers you've posted in the last 24-hours, appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?